# Script to execute .bat files and move them to a different folder

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have a program that creates .bat files to c:\temp.
I need to create a script that runs each .bat file inside c:\temp and moves them to c:\temp\backup after a successful execution.

How can i achieve this?
Thank you

Comment: Write your commands in a plain text file, give the file a `.bat`, or better a `.cmd`, extension and run it. This site isn't writing it for you, however there's a very good search facility at he top of each page, to assist you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code can be a good starting point.

1. Use the for loop to enumerate the files with .bat extension in the given directory.
2. Use the [call](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/call) command to execute.
3. Use the [move](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/move) command to move the file to other directory.

**Update:** As suggested in the comments, I added a basic error checking if the call command succeeded and only in the case of success, I am moving the bat file.

```
    @echo off
    set myDir=C:\temp\bats
    set doneDir=C:\temp\bats\done\

    md %doneDir%
    for %%I in ("%myDir%\*.bat") do (
       call %%I
       if %ERRORLEVEL% == 1 (          
            move %%I %doneDir%
       ) else (
            echo "error moving - %errorlevel%"
        )
    )
```

Comment: You missed the `after a **successful** execution` part...

Comment: I stated it's a good starting point. What else do you recommend?

Comment: change `move...` to `if not errorlevel 1 move...`

Comment: @Stephan - this makes sense. I edited the code.

Comment: shorter `for %%I in ("%myDir%\*.bat") do call %%I && move /Y "%%I" "%donedir% || echo unable to move %%i`

Comment: You'd need [delayed expansion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30282784/variables-are-not-behaving-as-expected/30284028#30284028) to make that work (that's why I suggested `if not errorlevel`, not `if %errorlevel% ==` (or rather `if !errorlevel! ==` here)